# Is there any reason for "saving" variables?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I've got this function a colleague once has written:

```
setSentence: function (e) {
  this.setState({
    issueText: e.target.value
  });

  if (this.refs.messages.textContent.length > 0 && e.target.value.length > 2) {
    this.refs.messages.textContent = '';
  }
},
```

He uses e.target.value on two places within the code. I would tend to make something like this:

```
let textBoxContent = e.target.value;
```

Then use the variable with the more descriptive name instead.

I once talked to him about these avoiding variables-thing. He just said that he wants "to save variables".

Would like to change these code-pieces but I'm still not sure ...

So therefore my question:

**Does "saving variables" respectively avoiding variables in the code make any sense?**

Comment: "Saving variables" sounds like micro-optimization to me. You should let the execution engine do its job, unless your domain requires otherwise.

Comment: It's an attempt at micro-optmization, which hinders code readability. It's generally not a good practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no economy in "saving variables" while repeating verbose code over and over.  To me, this definitely falls in the category of [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Javascript interpreters are very optimized for fast access to local variables.  When a variable is being referenced, the very first scope that is looked in is the local scope so it will be found immediately and because of that and because there is no outside access to local variables, code within the function using them can be optimized pretty well.

In the end, it's probably as much a personal coding preference as anything.

My personal rule is that if I have some multi-step reference such as `e.target.value` and I'm using it more than once in a function, then I will creating a meaningfully named local variable and assign it to that so I can then just use the local variable in the multiple places and avoid repeating the same multi-step property reference over and over (a textbook example of DRY).

This definitely makes the code easier to read too, both because you have a meaningful variable name and because it's just a simple variable rather than a multi-step property reference that has a generic name.  While, it might technically be one additional line of code for the local variable assignment, it saves a lot of repeated property lookups so the theory is that it should be faster to save the end value into `textBoxContent` and not have to have the interpreter lookup `e.target.value` every time.

---

Also, you should never fall for people who want to micro-optimize regular code as they first write it.  Optimizations like this generally only need apply to 0.000001% of all your code and only after you've proven exactly where your bottleneck for performance is.  And, even then you will have to devise multiple benchmarks in your target environment to prove what actually makes things faster (not use one person opinion - measurements only).

Before that, all your code should first be correct, clear, readable, maintainable, extensible, DRY, appropriate performance and about 10 other priorities before anyone thinks about a micro-optimization.  If you apply the above priorities to the case you asked about, you will always decide to assign `e.target.value` to a local variable if you are referencing it more than once within a context.

Comment: To be pedantic, DRY has a slightly more sophisticated meaning, which typically means not to duplicate data representations across tiers and layers. For example, do not duplicate a data schema once on the front-end and once on the back-end, in two different schema languages. DRY often implies some kind of pre-processor or DSL, which in the case of the schema example would involve somehow compiling a single schema into the versions needed by different elements of the system.

Comment: @torazaburo - I don't know if there is an exact definition of DRY.  I use the term to mean: "a principle of software development, aimed at reducing repetition of information of all kinds" which is taken right from the referenced wikipedia page.  So, multiple references to `e.target.value` in the same function is an avoidable repetition in my book.